# Transforming ReactiveMongo JSON with Play JSON

Tags: scala, playframework, reactivemongo, play-json, reactivemongo-play-json

ReactiveMongo's JSON functionality generates objects (`JsObject` in play-json parlance) rather than scalars for certain MongoDB datatypes like `BSONObjectID` and `BSONDateTime`. For example, you get JSON like this:

```
{
   "_id" : {
      "$oid" : "5de32e618f02001d8d521757"  //BSONObjectID
   },
   "createdAt" : {
      "$date" : 15751396221447 //BSONDateTime
   }
}
```

Aside from being cumbersome to deal with, I would prefer not to expose JSON that leaks MongoDB concerns to REST clients.

The tricky thing is that these values occur throughout the tree, so I need to write a Play JSON transformer smart enough to recursively transform the above at every level to look like this:

```
{
   "id" : "5de32e618f02001d8d521757",
   "createdAt" : 15751396221447 
}
```

One failed attempt to do this for just `BSONObjectID` is this:

```
(JsPath \ "_id").json.update(
    JsPath.read[JsObject].map{ o => o ++ Json.obj( "id" -> (o \ f"$$oid").as[String]) }
)
```

How can I do this?